# Websites hosted outside Germany seem to be inaccessible from VPS

Tags: dns, vps

I have a VPS mail server from the service provider Contabo running and today it has stopped being able to send mail to my gmail account. Digging into the problem I discovered that most domains don't respond to pinging, but some german sites like spiegel.de, amazon.de, deutschland.de and my other VPS servers hosted at Contabo (Contabo is a german VPS provider) are not affected. I think there must be some problem with the DNS settings, but I have no idea where to start investigating it. My other Contabo VPS servers are working fine, so I don't think this is a service wide problem.

Comment: well, directly ping IP addresses, not hostnames, to verify whether the problem lies in name resolution. Verify both IPv6 and IPv4 work.

Comment: You say “Website” in your title, but the rest of the question does not mention websites.

Comment: Try `ping 88.97.6.200` - this is in the UK. Using the IP address ensures you're bypassing any DNS issue. If that works you can try `ping roaima.co.uk`, which is the same target but using DNS for name resolution

Comment: And this is on-topic because ...?